# How To Refresh Weight On Sales Orders In Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to refresh the weight that appear in the Totals tab of a Sales Order in Acumatica? if you create a Sales Order and add an item with Weight say 2KG and save it, the Totals tab will correctly display 2KG. But then I changed the weight in the Inventory Item section to 5KG. Is there a way to get the Sales Order to update that weight (apart from deleting the item and adding it back)?

Thanks,
G

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: As far as I know, this is right behavior. If you change inventory item parameters, already created sales orders should not be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weight is stored at SO Line in the database and calculated automatically on selecting Inventory item.
Acumatica will automatically refresh default value when you update InvendoryItemID or UOM.

Not sure that this is best approach, but i can suggest 2 ways:

1) If you need it with non-programmatic way, you can use Export Scenarios to update UOM (and than change it back) for all Open/Hold orders.

2) Another is way with customization - create an action that will update wheigt. 
You can click this action automatically with using the same import scenarios or GI mass actions.

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {
    public PXAction<SOOrder> recalculateWeight;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Recalculate Weight", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update, Visible = false)]
    [PXButton(SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.Process)]
    public virtual void RecalculateWeight()
    {
      foreach(SOLine line in Base.Transactions.Select())
      {
        Base.Transactions.Cache.SetDefaultExt<SOLine.unitWeigth>(line);
        Base.Transactions.Update(line);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey, will give the customisation a try, sound good :)